# Polymer : Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: IntlMessageFormat is not defined

Tags: javascript, internationalization, polymer

I am using Plunker for an `i18n` demo with Polymer, but I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: IntlMessageFormat is not defined
```

[Plunker for i18n](https://plnkr.co/edit/JyjExwp5pjCmPqgErCtk?p=preview)

The default is English, which is also not displaying because of the above error. I'd like it to show:

```
My name is Batman.
```

And on changing the dropdown from `English` to `France`, the text should be changed to:

```
Je m'apelle Batman.
```

This code works fine on my local system, but not Plunker. What am I missing?

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers_"

Comment: Changed what is working and wt is not, the desired behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`intl-messageformat`](https://github.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat) is required, but is not available via `polygit` (at least I couldn't get it to work), but you can import it manually with this `<script>` tag *before* importing `<app-localize-behavior>`, which would allow your demo to work:

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat/v1.3.0/dist/intl-messageformat-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Working
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bkVGulEkRprXhBowwJeE?p=preview)

Comment: @MandeepSingh No problem